# parsing mutually exclusive optional and positional arguments followed by pass-thru arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to emulate the Python interpreter command-line behavior, as would be represented by the help text:

```
command [options] [-m mod | file] [arg] ...
```

That is:

- any number of arbitrary options (which are of the form `-[a-zA-Z]` that serve as a flag or with a single argument)
- one of:

  - -m mod
  - file
- zero or more arguments which should be available as-is

I have tried using the built-in argparse module, but unsuccessfully.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

selector = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
selector.add_argument('file', nargs='?', help='path to script')
selector.add_argument('-m', help='module name')

parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

parser.parse_args(['-m', 'hello', '--', 'arg1'])
```

Running this yields

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-m M] [file] ...
test.py: error: argument file: not allowed with argument -m
```

which makes sense, given that argparse seems to generally disregard the ordering of options - any positional arguments remaining after parsing options fill-in the positional arguments from first to last as specified.

I have tried defining custom `argparse.Action`s to do the job but it ends up looking pretty hacky, since the `Action` class corresponding to one of the arguments in the group needs to save an accumulated value for later inclusion in `args`.

I have also tried pre-processing the input to `parser.parse_args`, but do not like that approach since information about which options have values (to distinguish an option argument from the `file` argument) and which options are part of the group of terminal arguments (which should be considered the start of the pass-thru arguments `[arg] ...`) would be duplicated between the `argparse.add_argument`... calls and the pre-processing code.

What would be a good approach (other than requiring path to be provided with e.g. `-f`)?

Additional constraints:

- I prefer to use `argparse` or something with a nice interface that correlates the arguments to help text and doesn't take long to load (argparse imports in 6ms for me)
- I only need be compatible with Python 3.6 and above.
- It is not ideal, but I am OK requiring users to include `--` as the first `arg` if subsequent arguments (which would be passed through to the module or file) start with a `-` or may otherwise be mistaken for something in `[options]`.

Comment: I think if the `-m` was defined first, the mutually_exclusive usage would display correctly.  But that doesn't address the interference between the `?` of `file`, and strings intended for `args`.  `file` gets the first 'positional' string regardless of whether `-m` has been provided or not.

Comment: In general two positionals with variable number `nargs` don't work well together.  The first gets filled first.  The second only gets 'left overs', and may be 'satisfied' with an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Even without the mutually exclusive grouping, `file` and `args` don't play nicely together:

```
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                           
In [3]: parser.add_argument('-m');                                                    
In [4]: parser.add_argument('file', nargs='?');                                      
In [6]: parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER);
```

OK:

```
In [7]: parser.parse_args('-m foo a b c '.split())                                   
Out[7]: Namespace(args=['b', 'c'], file='a', m='foo')
```

'--' just lets us use '-b' as a plain string:

```
In [8]: parser.parse_args('-m foo a -- -b c '.split())                               
Out[8]: Namespace(args=['-b', 'c'], file='a', m='foo')
```

'a' goes to 'file', and rest to 'args' - that's because all 'contiguous' positionals are evaluated together.  With `remainder`, the `-m` flag is ignored, and treated like a plain string.

```
In [9]: parser.parse_args('a -m foo -- -b c '.split())                               
Out[9]: Namespace(args=['-m', 'foo', '--', '-b', 'c'], file='a', m=None)
In [10]: parser.parse_args('a -- -b c '.split())                                     
Out[10]: Namespace(args=['-b', 'c'], file='a', m=None)
```

Argument allocation occurs even before the `Action` is called, so custom Action classes don't alter this behavior.

Flagged arguments give you the best control - over order and mutual-exclusivity.

Comment: When I mention custom action classes - my approach was to have the action class check whether one of the mutually exclusive group had already been satisfied and, if so, save the argument value via a shimmed `type` function and keep the real value off to the side to be picked up be the argument accumulating all leftover values - it is not a good approach though and I could not invoking the parser multiples times unless I subclassed the parser itself to keep some state off to the side for each invocation of `parse_args`.

Comment: The way mutually_exclusive groups works is that at the start of parsing, it creates a `action_conflicts` dictionary.  Then right before acting on a action (`take_action`) it checks if this `action` conflicts with something in that group.  As part of that testing it maintains a `seen_non_default_actions`, which unfortunately is not visible outside of the `parse_args` function call.

Comment: If `self.default` is returned for all but one of the members of the mutually exclusive group then they pass that check.